# Can I create Facebook App with PHP SDK programatically?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-opengraph

Can I create Facebook apps programmatically?
Can I add a tab in a fan page for that app programmatically?

Comment: Ok, so what about http://www.socialshaker.com/ ?
It creates apps programmatically without configuring the app...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot programmatically add new Facebook apps via the API.  It is a purely mechanical process.  As a matter of fact, Facebook puts a captcha on the creation to prevent automated/programmatic creation..